# how mongodb scales when you have relationships between collections?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, nosql

I have a mongodb which links documents (the data cannot be embedded)

Does the mongos cluster (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/) support sharding when the documents are linked?

How this impacts the performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering there is nothing special about [referenced documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/database-references/), it is just a logical relationship inferred by the application layer and not MongoDB itself, sharding is supported. This applies for "manual" references, as well as DBRefs. You can even shard on a DBRef property, although I'm not sure as to why you'd want to considering a DBRef should have inherently low cardinality.

There is an impact in performance for both manual and DBRefs, in that multiple queries must be performed to "join" the data. From the docs:

> To resolve DBRefs, your application must perform additional queries to
>   return the referenced documents. Many drivers have helper methods that
>   form the query for the DBRef automatically. The drivers do not
>   automatically resolve DBRefs into documents.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "document links" in MongoDB. Just fields in documents of collection A which happen to have the same values as fields of documents in collection B. DBRef's are just a conversion on the application layer and get no special treatment whatsoever by the database.

What matters for sharding efficiency is how you define the [shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) for the referenced collection. When the field you search by is part of the shard key of the collection, mongos can accelerate it by redirecting the query to the correct shard.

You likely want all documents of collection A which belong to the same document of collection B to reside on the same shard. That means you should have the shard key of A include the field of A which is an unique identifier of B (objectID, name or whatever).